# List windows route table

Tags: c, windows, routes, windows-networking, iphelper

I want to list entries from windows route table. Same output as from `route print`. I use `GetIpForwardTable2` function from IP Helper API. But I get some weird results which differ from route command output.
I run it in Windows 7 64bit in VirtualBox where I have 3 network cards (NAT, Bridge and Internal Network) and compile it under cygwin with following command:

```
gcc -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -DNTDDI_VERSION=0x06010000 win-iproute.c -liphlpapi
```

Those `_WIN32_WINNT` and `NTDDI_VERSION` are just to make functionality from Win7 available.
To make it simplier I consider ipv4 only now.

Here is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <Mstcpip.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  DWORD retval;
  MIB_IPFORWARD_TABLE2 *routes = NULL;
  MIB_IPFORWARD_ROW2 *route;
  int idx;

  retval = GetIpForwardTable2(AF_INET, &routes);
  if (retval != ERROR_SUCCESS)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "GetIpForwardTable2 failed (0x%x)\n.", retval);
    return 1;
  }

  printf("Route entries count: %lu\n", routes->NumEntries);

  for (idx = 0; idx < routes->NumEntries; idx++)
  {
    printf("\n -- Entry #%d -- \n", idx);
    route = routes->Table + idx;
    printf("luid: \t\t Reserved: %u, NetLuidIndex %u, IfType %u\n",
      route->InterfaceLuid.Info.Reserved,
      route->InterfaceLuid.Info.NetLuidIndex,
      route->InterfaceLuid.Info.IfType);
    printf("protocol: \t %lu\n", route->Protocol);
    printf("origin: \t %lu\n", route->Origin);
    printf("loopback: \t %lu\n", route->Loopback);
    printf("next hop: \t %s\n", inet_ntoa(route->NextHop.Ipv4.sin_addr));
    printf("site prefix length: \t %u\n", route->SitePrefixLength);
    printf("prefix length: \t %u\n", route->DestinationPrefix.PrefixLength);
    printf("prefix : \t %s\n", inet_ntoa(route->DestinationPrefix.Prefix.Ipv4.sin_addr));
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
Route entries count: 22

 -- Entry #0 --
luid:            Reserved: 0, NetLuidIndex 6, IfType 6
protocol:        0
origin:          0
loopback:        0
next hop:        0.0.0.0
site prefix length:      0
prefix length:   0
prefix :         0.0.0.0

 -- Entry #1 --
luid:            Reserved: 0, NetLuidIndex 0, IfType 0
protocol:        0
origin:          0
loopback:        0
next hop:        0.0.0.0
site prefix length:      0
prefix length:   3
prefix :         0.0.0.0

 -- Entry #2 --
luid:            Reserved: 0, NetLuidIndex 0, IfType 0
protocol:        4294967295
origin:          257
loopback:        0
next hop:        0.0.0.0
site prefix length:      0
prefix length:   10
prefix :         0.1.0.0

 -- Entry #3 --
luid:            Reserved: 17, NetLuidIndex 0, IfType 0
protocol:        11
origin:          0
loopback:        2
next hop:        0.0.0.0
site prefix length:      17
prefix length:   0
prefix :         2.0.0.0

 -- Entry #4 --
luid:            Reserved: 0, NetLuidIndex 0, IfType 0
protocol:        32
origin:          0
loopback:        2
next hop:        0.1.0.0
site prefix length:      0
prefix length:   255
prefix :         2.0.0.0

 -- Entry #5 --
luid:            Reserved: 0, NetLuidIndex 0, IfType 0
protocol:        0
origin:          256
loopback:        255
next hop:        0.0.0.0
site prefix length:      0
prefix length:   11
prefix :         255.255.255.255

 -- Entry #6 --
luid:            Reserved: 3, NetLuidIndex 65792, IfType 0
protocol:        201326592
origin:          2
loopback:        0
next hop:        0.0.0.0
site prefix length:      3
prefix length:   24
prefix :         0.0.6.0

 -- Entry #7 --
luid:            Reserved: 5855577, NetLuidIndex 89, IfType 0
protocol:        0
origin:          2
loopback:        0
next hop:        0.1.0.0
site prefix length:      89
prefix length:   0
prefix :         0.0.0.0

 -- Entry #8 --
luid:            Reserved: 0, NetLuidIndex 0, IfType 0
protocol:        0
origin:          4294967295
loopback:        0
next hop:        2.0.0.0
site prefix length:      0
prefix length:   0
prefix :         0.0.0.0

 -- Entry #9 --
luid:            Reserved: 16777215, NetLuidIndex 65791, IfType 0
protocol:        593
origin:          1572864
loopback:        0
next hop:        2.0.0.0
site prefix length:      255
prefix length:   0
prefix :         0.0.0.0

 -- Entry #10 --
luid:            Reserved: 1, NetLuidIndex 512, IfType 0
protocol:        0
origin:          0
loopback:        0
next hop:        255.255.255.255
site prefix length:      1
prefix length:   0
prefix :         0.0.0.0

 -- Entry #11 --
luid:            Reserved: 4, NetLuidIndex 512, IfType 0
protocol:        0
origin:          0
loopback:        0
next hop:        0.0.6.0
site prefix length:      4
prefix length:   81
prefix :         0.0.0.0

 -- Entry #12 --
luid:            Reserved: 0, NetLuidIndex 16776960, IfType 65535
protocol:        3
origin:          1
loopback:        0
next hop:        0.0.0.0
site prefix length:      0
prefix length:   0
prefix :         0.1.0.0

 -- Entry #13 --
luid:            Reserved: 0, NetLuidIndex 12, IfType 6
protocol:        4294967295
origin:          0
loopback:        0
next hop:        0.0.0.0
site prefix length:      0
prefix length:   0
prefix :         0.0.0.0

 -- Entry #14 --
luid:            Reserved: 0, NetLuidIndex 0, IfType 0
protocol:        0
origin:          0
loopback:        0
next hop:        0.0.0.0
site prefix length:      0
prefix length:   3
prefix :         0.0.0.0

 -- Entry #15 --
luid:            Reserved: 0, NetLuidIndex 0, IfType 0
protocol:        4294967295
origin:          257
loopback:        0
next hop:        0.0.0.0
site prefix length:      0
prefix length:   255
prefix :         0.1.0.0

 -- Entry #16 --
luid:            Reserved: 585, NetLuidIndex 0, IfType 0
protocol:        3449440
origin:          0
loopback:        0
next hop:        0.0.0.0
site prefix length:      73
prefix length:   0
prefix :         2.0.0.0

 -- Entry #17 --
luid:            Reserved: 3211321, NetLuidIndex 13056, IfType 65
protocol:        3342403
origin:          4325427
loopback:        49
next hop:        125.0.0.0
site prefix length:      53
prefix length:   68
prefix :         54.0.45.0

 -- Entry #18 --
luid:            Reserved: 3473453, NetLuidIndex 17408, IfType 54
protocol:        0
origin:          0
loopback:        0
next hop:        0.0.0.0
site prefix length:      0
prefix length:   0
prefix :         70.0.69.0

 -- Entry #19 --
luid:            Reserved: 0, NetLuidIndex 0, IfType 0
protocol:        7471205
origin:          7274610
loopback:        0
next hop:        115.0.97.0
site prefix length:      111
prefix length:   0
prefix :         0.0.0.0

 -- Entry #20 --
luid:            Reserved: 7274611, NetLuidIndex 26112, IfType 116
protocol:        3277144
origin:          50725
loopback:        0
next hop:        49.69.55.56
site prefix length:      51
prefix length:   56
prefix :         65.0.100.0

 -- Entry #21 --
luid:            Reserved: 3277144, NetLuidIndex 0, IfType 0
protocol:        0
origin:          0
loopback:        0
next hop:        0.0.0.0
site prefix length:      192
prefix length:   0
prefix :         16.0.0.0
```

While the output of `route print -4` is following:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 16...08 00 27 7e 98 16 ......Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter #3
 14...08 00 27 86 3d 31 ......Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter #2
 11...08 00 27 42 d2 16 ......Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 15...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
 17...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.2.2        10.0.2.15     10
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.0.0.138        10.0.0.36     10
         10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link         10.0.0.36    266
        10.0.0.36  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.0.36    266
       10.0.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.0.36    266
         10.0.2.0    255.255.255.0         On-link         10.0.2.15    266
        10.0.2.15  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.2.15    266
       10.0.2.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.2.15    266
       89.89.89.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       89.89.89.89    266
      89.89.89.89  255.255.255.255         On-link       89.89.89.89    266
     89.89.89.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       89.89.89.89    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         10.0.2.15    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         10.0.0.36    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       89.89.89.89    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.2.15    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.0.0.36    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       89.89.89.89    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

There is a lot of weird stuff in the code output. Many entries have undocumented values, for example:

- `Protocol` should be within range 1-14 (almost non entry has such value)
- `Luid.IfType` shouldn't be 0 (again almost all are zero)
- almost non entry gives any reasonable `Prefix`

It's described here [MIB_IPFORWARD_ROW2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa814494%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and here [NET_LUID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Should I just ignore those with invalid values? and if so where are the valid ones? Or am I doing something terribly wrong?

I also discovered that when I start Windows with cables unplugged it gives less entries (which makes sense). Then I plug in the cables and entries are added. But when I unplug again they are still there. `route` command works as expected, when cable is unplugged entries are reduced.

When I try older function `GetIpForwardTable` it works. But it doesn't support ipv6.

Comment: It seems  that there is some issue within the cygwin. When I compile the code above in Visual Studio it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems that the problem was in cygwin. When I compile the example code with Microsoft C compiler `cl.ex` it works as expected. And after update of cygwin it works when compiled using gcc too.
Interesting is that it was enough to update the packages using cygwin installer, `cygwin1.dll` can remain in older version.